# flutter Text Button padding issue

Tags: flutter, padding

I have two types of TextButton widget to be used in ListView().
They are identical(copy&paste) except for onPressed attribute.
One takes a widget and show it with Navigator.push.
One takes a VoidCallback and run it.
Other styling part are exactly the same.

```
Widget ListTextLinkButton({required BuildContext context, required String text, required Widget page}) {
  return Container(
    height: _listItemHeight,
    child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        TextButton(
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            ),
            child: Text(text,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: _buttonTextSize,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page));
            }
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}


Widget ListTextActionButton({required BuildContext context, required String text, required onPressed}) {
  return Container(
    height: _listItemHeight,
    child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        TextButton(
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            ),
            child: Text(text,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: _buttonTextSize,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
            ),
            onPressed: onPressed
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

But when I put them inside ListView like this,

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: ...
  body: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.sp),
    children: <Widget>[
      ListTitle(context: context, text: '기타'),
      ListTextLinkButton(context: context, text: '서비스 이용 약관', page: UserAgreementPage('terms-of-service')),
      ListTextLinkButton(context: context, text: '개인정보 수집 및 활용 동의서', page: UserAgreementPage('privacy-policy')),
      ListTextActionButton(context: context, text: '로그아웃', onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            signOut();
      }),
      ListTextActionButton(context: context, text: '탈퇴하기', onPressed: (){}),
])),
```

This is what I get.
[image]

Where does the extra padding come from? Can anyone explain how the TextButton padding works??

Answer (score 1):

Please wrap it with `SizedBox( child : TextButton(), height: 10.00 , width : 10.00)` as in flutter widgets have thier predefined padding.So, this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I try your code and found that character text in your **ListTextActionButton** make empty space in front of text.